# GML/SVG for indoor map in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, svg, gml, indoor

I am new to GIS world and trying to incorporate OpenLayers with GML or SVG.

I am building a map engine and one of the features should be support of ***indoor maps***. It can be accomplished with a static image, but I got a requirement that the engine has to ***understand vector format***, the main reason is to keep a good quality when you zoom in or zoom out.

> Common use case: the client has an indoor map (floor plan) made in
>   AutoCAD, so it can be exported to GIS formats.

I do not understand how to make it work. I should define the projection but I have no clue which number should be assigned if I only want to show my floor. Regarding the static image, I could create a custom projection, but how to deal with GML?

To be honest I can do it with SVG if someone helps me to correctly set up the image size because now it shows the only limited part of the image.

I read SVG data

```
 viewBox="0 0 1024 768"
```

and set extent accordingly

```
var extent = [0, 0, 1024, 768]
```

besides that, I pointed out the image size

```
 imageSize: [1024, 768]
```

it seems to be a trivial task, but not for me.

I prepared [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxfzcak5/35/) (wait a few seconds until it loads  SVG file)

**UPD:  I managed to make it work with SVG, but anyway it looks blurry when zoom in and image located not in the center**

Comment: Maybe better switch to Leaflet. It seems to be more friendly for front end developers